# find not greedy matches of phrase in text with preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I want to search a document for a phrase (long tail keyword in this case) but want to allow spaces/words in between the searched words.

for example, my text is:

"ShinyTeeth inc is an excellent dental clinic based in Chattanooga, Tennessee."

And I'm looking for "**dental clinic chattanooga tennessee**"

"CrookedTeeth inc is an excellent **dental**  **clinic** based in **Chattanooga**, **Tennessee**."

I need a regular expression that can find my keywords in the text with an allowance of X space/words between each keyword. in this case for example, up to two words spacing so it can Identify my keyword as found in my text.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the keyword order matter? If the search was for *"chattanooga dental tennessee clinic"* should it still match?

Comment: The easiest way would be with the original order I assume, remember that we can allow up to X (let's say 2) words in between keywords, its not an overall match all across the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching string literals in PHP with Regex can be difficult if you're trying to match multiple phrases. It might be best to do this sort of thing with a MySQL Full Text search on a database. That being said, here are a few strings and a couple of regex patterns I was testing out.

```
<?php

$strings= array('Chattanooga Tennessee dental practice.',
"ShinyTeeth inc is an excellent dental clinic based in Chattanooga, Tennessee.",
"My dentist SmileyTeeth in chattanooga tennessee has the coolest practice.",
"And I'm looking for \"dental clinic chattanooga tennessee\"",
"CrookedTeeth inc is an excellent dental clinic located in Chattanooga, Tennessee.");

$patterns = array(
'!((dental office|dentist|dental practice|dental clinic)[^\s.]?\s+([^\s.]+\s?){0,2}\s+[^\s.]?(Chattanooga(,)?)? (Tennessee)?)!is',
'!((dental|dentist|doctor)\s+(clinic|practice|office)\s+([^\s]+\s?){0,2}\s+(Chattanooga(,)?)? (Tennessee)?)!is',

);
foreach($strings as $string){
    foreach($patterns as $pattern){

        if(preg_match($pattern,$string)){
            echo "\n`$pattern` \"matches\"\n $string\n";
        } else {
            echo "\n`$pattern` \"does not match\"\n $string\n";         
        }
    }

}
?>
```

**Output**

> `!((dental office|dentist|dental practice|dental
>   clinic)[^\s.]?\s+([^\s.]+\s?){0,2}\s+[^\s.]?(Chattanooga(,)?)?
>   (Tennessee)?)!is` "does not match"  Chattanooga Tennessee dental
>   practice.
>
> `!((dental|dentist|doctor)\s+(clinic|practice|office)\s+([^\s]+\s?){0,2}\s+(Chattanooga(,)?)?
>   (Tennessee)?)!is` "does not match"  Chattanooga Tennessee dental
>   practice.
>
> `!((dental office|dentist|dental practice|dental
>   clinic)[^\s.]?\s+([^\s.]+\s?){0,2}\s+[^\s.]?(Chattanooga(,)?)?
>   (Tennessee)?)!is` "matches"  ShinyTeeth inc is an excellent dental
>   clinic based in Chattanooga, Tennessee.
>
> `!((dental|dentist|doctor)\s+(clinic|practice|office)\s+([^\s]+\s?){0,2}\s+(Chattanooga(,)?)?
>   (Tennessee)?)!is` "matches"  ShinyTeeth inc is an excellent dental
>   clinic based in Chattanooga, Tennessee.
>
> `!((dental office|dentist|dental practice|dental
>   clinic)[^\s.]?\s+([^\s.]+\s?){0,2}\s+[^\s.]?(Chattanooga(,)?)?
>   (Tennessee)?)!is` "matches"  My dentist SmileyTeeth in chattanooga
>   tennessee has the coolest practice.
>
> `!((dental|dentist|doctor)\s+(clinic|practice|office)\s+([^\s]+\s?){0,2}\s+(Chattanooga(,)?)?
>   (Tennessee)?)!is` "does not match"  My dentist SmileyTeeth in
>   chattanooga tennessee has the coolest practice.
>
> `!((dental office|dentist|dental practice|dental
>   clinic)[^\s.]?\s+([^\s.]+\s?){0,2}\s+[^\s.]?(Chattanooga(,)?)?
>   (Tennessee)?)!is` "does not match"  And I'm looking for "dental clinic
>   chattanooga tennessee"
>
> `!((dental|dentist|doctor)\s+(clinic|practice|office)\s+([^\s]+\s?){0,2}\s+(Chattanooga(,)?)?
>   (Tennessee)?)!is` "does not match"  And I'm looking for "dental clinic
>   chattanooga tennessee"
>
> `!((dental office|dentist|dental practice|dental
>   clinic)[^\s.]?\s+([^\s.]+\s?){0,2}\s+[^\s.]?(Chattanooga(,)?)?
>   (Tennessee)?)!is` "matches"  CrookedTeeth inc is an excellent dental
>   clinic located in Chattanooga, Tennessee.
>
> `!((dental|dentist|doctor)\s+(clinic|practice|office)\s+([^\s]+\s?){0,2}\s+(Chattanooga(,)?)?
>   (Tennessee)?)!is` "matches"  CrookedTeeth inc is an excellent dental
>   clinic located in Chattanooga, Tennessee.